# Multi-page equations -- problem

Tags: equations, page-breaking

I have a very long derivation, that needs to look like:

> A = B \\ = C \\ = D \\

etc. The derivation spans across many lines. I'm looking for a way to typeset it so that when it reaches the end of the page it can continue naturally on the next page, without trying to fit the entire equation into a single page. I'm currently using eqnarray and it insists that all its contents sit on a single page.

Can anyone suggest another environment that supports multi-page equations?

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray` use `align`. I don't know if this solves that problem. But just in general, don't use `eqnarray`

Comment: Take a look at a special [PracTeX Journal article](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen) to learn why not to use the `eqnarray` environment anymore.

Answer (score 82):

With `align`, page breaks in multi line equations are possible. The command `\allowdisplaybreaks` enables it. You can fine-tune it optionally:

- `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` : page breaks are allowed, but avoided if possible
- `\allowdisplaybreaks[2]`, ..., `\allowdisplaybreaks[4]` : page breaks are allowed, more relaxed

You can still use `\\*` to forbid a page break at places where it's undesirable.

While `\allowdisplaybreaks` goes into the preamble, you could also allow page breaks at certain places in the body text by `\displaybreak`:

- `\displaybreak[0]` : allows a page break after the following `\\`, but doesn't encourage it
- `\displaybreak[1]`, ..., `\displaybreak[3]` : allows a page breaks, more relaxed
- `\displaybreak[4]` : forces a page break after the following `\\`

4 is the default value for both `\displaybreak` and `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

See: *3.9 Vertical spacing and page breaks in multiline displays* in the [amsmath user's guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).

Answer (score 20):

Just add the `\allowdisplaybreaks` command from the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package to the preamble of your document. Works only with the math environments provided by this package. The manual describes the details. Take a look at the excellent »[Math mode](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)« document for more information about math typesetting.