# Aligned equation which can break through pages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-breaking, amsmath, align, breqn

I'm writing long sequences of aligned math equations, and LaTeX interprete them as single, unbreakable objects... which is Ok if the equation is nowhere near the end of the page.

**Q:** Is there a way to (automatically) break the align equation through pages?

In the code below,

```
\documentclass{report}                                                          
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
\usepackage{lipsum}                                                             

\begin{document}                                                                
\lipsum[1-4]                                                                    
\begin{align*}                                                                  
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF &= \partial_t(p)\\                                                            
  &= \partial_t(m v)\\                                                          
  &= m a\\                                                                      
  &= m \dot{v}\\                                                                
  &= m \ddot{x}\\                                                               
  &= \partial_t(p)\\                                                            
  &= \partial_t(m v)\\                                                          
  &= ma\\                                                                      
  &= m \dot{v}\\                                                                
  &= m \ddot{x}                                                                 
\end{align*}                                                                    
\end{document}
```

all of the equation goes to the second page. I **do not** want that

If I break manually, by closing the `align` and open another, I lose the alignment with the previous part.

```
\documentclass{report}                                                          
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
\usepackage{lipsum}                                                             

\begin{document}                                                                
\lipsum[1-4]                                                                    
\begin{align*}                                                                  
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF &= \partial_t(p)\\                                                            
  &= \partial_t(m v)\\                                                          
  &= m a\\                                                                      
  &= m \dot{v}\\                                                                
  &= m \ddot{x}\\                                                               
\end{align*}                                                                    
\begin{align*}                                                                  
  &= \partial_t(p)\\                                                            
  &= \partial_t(m v)\\                                                          
  &= m a\\                                                                      
  &= m \dot{v}\\                                                                
  &= m \ddot{x}                                                                 
\end{align*}                                                                    
\end{document}
```

I **do not** want that either.

So far I read about `breqn` packages, but it seems not to do what I would like.

Any Suggestion?? Thx.

Comment: we should probably close as duplicate then? (Stefan goes in to more detail there, although it's not accepted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\displaybreak` to force a break after a specified line or add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble to allow them generally.

Comment: Thank you @david-calister. I follow your suggestion, it worked like a charm! Also found [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24903/multi-page-equations-problem). Cheers.

Comment: @Dox Just a friendly reminder: [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. :-)

Comment: @sean-allred Got it present, but the answer was so fast that the page do not allow an acceptance yet! :-P