# Breaking equation through pages

Tags: page-breaking, breqn

In a [former post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119158/aligned-equation-which-can-break-through-pages) I learnt how to break an align equation by using the `\allowdisplaybreaks` command on the preamble.

However, I found the package `breqn`, which is impressive! So far I've been unable to found a way to allow page-break-equations using `dmath` environment.

Does anyone know if it is possible? If so... How could I do that?

Interesting references: [TUGboat ref.](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-3/tb56down.pdf) and [Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf)

Comment: if you are talking about page-breaking what is essentially a single equation (that is, an equation that would be identified by a single equation number), my understanding is that this is equivalent to the `amsmath` `aligned` or `split`, which are not meant to be broken over the end of a page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your comment is as accurate as it can be! The package was not designed to allow page-breaking of equations. I was hoping that someone could help with a tweak to (say) enhance the package to include this feature! I know it is unlikely, but if anyone can help, it should be around the forum... Isn't it? XD (Note: that I'd like to help, but my programming skills are not as developed as I'd like them to be)

Comment: making this feature possible would be more than i'd be inclined to consider a "tweak"; more in the nature of an overhaul, and that only after a thorough consideration of how to treat the single equation number.  (there's a [subsidiary document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn-technotes.pdf) that's part of the `breqn` package on ctan that discusses the problems already encountered in that respect.)