# Problem with \begin{align}

Tags: spacing, amsmath, align

I am using `\begin{align}` in my paper. Hence unwanted gaps are being created to accomodate the whole `\begin{align}` content in one page. how to prevent it ?

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreaks` ?

Comment: So the `align` environment has a lot of content and doesn't break across the page boundary? Reduce the amount of content then, or issue `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble (see [Multi-page equations — problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24903/5764)).